# Does the academic community perceive letters and short articles differently from longer articles?

Tags: publications, journals, impact-factor

There are some journals that accept short articles of 2 to 4 pages.

I have submitted (and had accepted) such a letter (Cannot specifically name the letter) which is 2 pages in length but it is a SCI-E journal.

How would such an article be viewed by the academic community? Is there a big difference between the two?

Similarly, how does academics view journals that only publish such short articles?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be clearer on what you mean by 'standing' of a letter? Do you mean is it considered a worthwhile thing to do? (Note that Physical Review Letters and Applied Physics Letters are well regarded.)

Comment: By 'standing' I mean how does the professors, academics see such publications while considering offering post-docs or job offers.

Comment: I’m sorry, but we can’t comment on the effects of individual journals.

Comment: The arguments and conclusions of a paper should stand on their own, no matter the length. After all, Fermat caused quite a stir with one line written in the margin of a book. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem

Comment: Thanks, @aeismail for change in title. It looks more academic now. But still, I don't understand why is this question on hold as it is a genuine question. How else do I get to know the answer to the question I have?

Comment: I’ve removed the hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an interesting study of ecology papers by [Fox et al.](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/ece3.2505), finding that at least in that field, longer papers tend to be cited more. The explanation they advance, however, is that longer papers contain "more and a greater diversity of data and ideas," not that scientists feel more warmly about long papers than short ones. Also, the effect size they found was small, with less than a 2% increase in citations per 10% increase in page number. This suggests that padding out a short paper with extra analyses is not an efficient way to raise its profile.

(Short papers, of course, can be very influential: the first paper to accurately describe the structure of DNA was [almost exactly one page](http://www.sns.ias.edu/~tlusty/courses/landmark/WatsonCrick1953.pdf).)